# Ultrametric Binary Strings

Tags: metric-spaces, computer-science, binary

All metric spaces obey the triangle inequality which is, for three points $a,b,c$, that

$$d(a,c) \le d(a,b) + d(b,c)$$

One interesting special case of a metric space is one endowed with an ultrametric structure, in which case the triangle inequality is replaced by the stronger inequality

$$ d(a,c) \le \text{max} \{ d(a,b), d(b,c) \} \,. $$

Ultrametric spaces occur in many fields of study, and naturally describe spaces with a tree-like structure.

I have been working on a project involving spin-glasses, and one of the interesting mathematical properties of the spin-glass phase is that the space of states is ultrametric. I am wondering if there are any other examples from computer science, where ultrametricity shows up. I am particularly interested when the space of states are $n$-bit binary strings, $\{0,1\}^n$, and the distance measure $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Hamming distance. Clearly $n$-bit binary strings are not ultrametric on their own, but perhaps there are situations where the $n$-bit strings are naturally restricted in such a way that over the constrained space of bit strings the ultrametric property is satisfied.

Comment: I am a little confused about what your question is.  Are you asking for examples of natural phenomena that have an ultrametric structure?

Comment: For the binary string example, I think you will get an ultrametric if you take $d(a, b) = 1/i$ where $i$ is the first index position at which $a$ and $b$ differ (and of course $d(a, b)=0$ if $a = b$). This is related to the [p-adic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) with $p = 2$.

Comment: I am interested in examples where ultrametricity shows up specifically involving binary strings and the hamming distance. I thought there might be examples from computer science that I was unaware of, in addition to the natural phenomena examples such as spin-glasses or evolutionary trees.

Comment: @rob-arthan The two ultrametrics you suggest are not really related. In particular, the completions of the free monoid for these two ultrametrics are different.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin:   It's related in that it's looking at the first difference. I wasn't claiming anything deeper.

Comment: @rob-arthan Allright, then.

Comment: The problem with your question is that the space $\{0,1\}^n$ is finite...

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Aren't all metrics on a finite set strongly equivalent, and in particular strongly equivalent to the discrete metric?